# Skip an already reviewed android app version on Play Store

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

Due to some reason, I do not wish to publish the already reviewed, App on Play Store. (Let's call this the buggy version - v1.0.3(5))

I have a new version uploaded with bugs fixed and version updated - v1.0.4(6)

I have Managed Publishing turned on.

What will be the behaviour after I click on publish changes. (When both versions are ready to publish).

Note: I do not want any user to use the buggy version - v1.0.3(5)

[image: Current State on play store console]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the review of newer version 1.0.4(6), the older version does not show up in ready to publish changes. [image]

Comment: Did they take the same time to review the updated version or was it faster?